# Prove that inequality holds for zeros of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $P_n(z)= a_n z^n+...+a_1z +a_0$, $n\geq 1$, $a_i \in \mathbb{C}$, $(i=0,...,n)$, $a_n\neq0$, $a_0\neq 0$, $M=max_{j \in \{0,...,n-1\}} |a_j|$, $m=min_{j \in \{1,...,n\}} |a_j|$. Prove that for all zeros $w$ of polynomial $P_n$ following holds:

$$ \frac{1}{1+\frac{m}{|a_0|} }\leq |w| \leq 1 + \frac{M}{|a_n|}$$

Could someone give a hint how to prove this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Here is one hint: the two inequalities are effectively both the same, because $w$ is a root of $a_nz^n+\cdots+a_0$ if and only if $1/w$ is a root of $a_0z^n+\cdots+a_n$.

Comment: But $m$ should be a max not a min I think.  Otherwise $2z^2-1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: If $P(z)=2z^2-1$ then $m=\min(0,2)=0$ and $w=\pm1/\sqrt2$, so your left hand inequality says $1\le1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: Maybe the formulation is wrong. What if we change min to max, as you said, can some similar statement be proved?

Comment: Divide by $a_n$ and use triangle inequality to get $|w^n| \le M|w^k|/|a_n|$ for the$k<n$ for which $M=|a_k|$; then either $M/|a_n|\le 1$ when $|w|\le 1$ or $M/|a_n|\ge 1$ when $|w|\le M/|a_n|$ so done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint as requested: let $w$ be a root of the polynomial and assume $|w|>1+M/|a_n|$.  Then
$$\eqalign{|w|
  &=\frac{1}{|a_n|}\Bigl|-a_{n-1}-\frac{a_{n-2}}{w}-\cdots-\frac{a_0}{w^{n-1}}\Bigr|\cr
  &=\frac{M}{|a_n|}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{|w|}+\cdots+\frac{1}{|w|^{n-1}}\Bigr)\cr
  &<\frac{M}{|a_n|}\frac{1}{1-1/|w|}\cr
  &<1+\frac{M}{|a_n|}\ .\cr}$$